# Getting started guide for Jhipster 4 latest state

Tags: jhipster

Can someone post getting started guide for Jhipster 4.0 with angular 2?
I don't care if it is not released. I just want to generate code with latest code on github and move on.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question for stackoverflow users, but a request to JHipster maintainers.

Comment: +1 from me. I'm the lead dev of the project, and I too have trouble working correctly with our AngularJS 2 support!

Comment: @JulienDubois Thanks a lot. You are such a nice person in addition to your contribution.

Comment: Hello JB:
DO you know there are millions user are waiting for   Jhipster 4.0?
Why are you think  only jhipster maintainers need to know about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update - wikipage published by Deepu on github:
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/NG2-GUIDE.md

I figured out myself. But I cannot speak for the current state since I am not a developer.

- Installation prerequisites:

  > JDK(and JAVA_HOME env variable set), git client, npm, maven or gradle
- First create a directory where you want to clone jhipster angular-2 branch. Then from that directory execute:

> git clone  -b angular-2  --single-branch https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster.git
>
> cd generator-jhipster
>
> npm link
>
> npm install -g gulp bower

- Create app directory and from there

> yo jhipster

Ignore upgrade offer and in the second question select Angular-2(beta)

- Run the app

In case you picked Maven:

> mvn spring-boot:run

In case you picked Gradle:

> gradle bootRun

Comment: Shouldn't it be gulp-cli rather than gulp in `npm install -g gulp-cli bower`?

Comment: Here is the official docs https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/angular-2/NG2-GUIDE.md

Comment: @Deepu following the link leads me to a 404 page. do you know where it went?

Comment: The branch has been merged into master please look for the same file in master branch